# Numpy: Efficient search for an array into the other one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have got two arrays like those below:

```
first_array = np.array([2,2,2,10,10,15,20,20,20,20])
second_array = np.array([15,5,10,78,2,44,20,2,66,1,10,15,40,85,71,23,20,45,29,20,1])
```

I want to search for each element of the first array inside the second one to end up with  a 2D array which includes the indexes of the second array and the values searched.

The codes below are working and giving what I desire to me, but they also seem definitely inefficient to me. There must exist an index operation or some different approaches rather than applying element by element search (loop).

```
out = []
for i in first_array:
    index = np.argwhere(second_array == i)
    out.append(np.array([*index.T,np.ones(len(index))*i]))
    
np.hstack(out).T
```

Here is the desired output for those who don't want to run the codes.

```
desired_output = np.array([[4,7,4,7,4,7,2,10,2,10,0,11,6,16,19,6,16,19,6,16,19,6,16,19],
                         [2,2,2,2,2,2,10,10,10,10,15,15,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]]).T
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to think of two solutions:

1. Broadcast comparison, but this is still the `O(mn)` algorithm (m = len(first_array) and n = len(second_array)):

```
>>> i, j = (first_array[:, None] == second_array).nonzero()
>>> np.array([j, first_array[i]]).T
array([[ 4,  2],
       [ 7,  2],
       [ 4,  2],
       [ 7,  2],
       [ 4,  2],
       [ 7,  2],
       [ 2, 10],
       [10, 10],
       [ 2, 10],
       [10, 10],
       [ 0, 15],
       [11, 15],
       [ 6, 20],
       [16, 20],
       [19, 20],
       [ 6, 20],
       [16, 20],
       [19, 20],
       [ 6, 20],
       [16, 20],
       [19, 20],
       [ 6, 20],
       [16, 20],
       [19, 20]], dtype=int64)
```

2. Use the dictionary to build the mapping between elements and indices. If don't consider the final concatenating result step, this is the `O(m + n)` algorithm. However, in the current example, the performance is not as good as the first solution:

```
>>> mp = {}
>>> for i, val in enumerate(first_array):
...     mp.setdefault(val, []).append(i)
...
>>> np.concatenate([(indices := mp[val], [val] * len(indices))
...                 for val in first_array], -1).T
array([[ 4,  2],
       [ 7,  2],
       [ 4,  2],
       [ 7,  2],
       [ 4,  2],
       [ 7,  2],
       [ 2, 10],
       [10, 10],
       [ 2, 10],
       [10, 10],
       [ 0, 15],
       [11, 15],
       [ 6, 20],
       [16, 20],
       [19, 20],
       [ 6, 20],
       [16, 20],
       [19, 20],
       [ 6, 20],
       [16, 20],
       [19, 20],
       [ 6, 20],
       [16, 20],
       [19, 20]])
```